# Inserting multiple rows with column into single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query to copy set of rows from one table to another table in this format

```
Table 1
ColumnName     ColumnValue    RowId

Column1              Value1           1
Column2              Value2           1
Column3              Value3           1
Column1              Value4           2
Column2              Value5           2
Column3              Value6           2
Column1              Value7           3
Column2              Value8           3
Column3              Value9           3

Table2
Column1         Column2     Column3  
Value1          Value2       Value3      
Value4          Value5       Value6
Value7          Value8       Value9
```

Here basically table 1 is input and table 2 is the output which I am trying. I used the pivot and row number but none worked.

What will be the insert query to achieve this. Here all rows of rowId 1 from table 1 will form form one row of table2.

Comment: is there always a set number of columns?

Comment: Yes there will be only 3 columns. Column name will be unique only. I tried pivoting on column but was not able to write insert using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select rowID, 
       max(case when columnName = 'Column1' then value else null end) as column1,
       max(case when columnName = 'Column2' then value else null end) as column2,
       max(case when columnName = 'Column3' then value else null end) as column3
from table1
group by rowID
```

Comment: Thanks but I have to write a insert query for the same to dump data in table 2.

Comment: ok... and why is that an issue just put `insert into table2 (c1, c2, c3, c4) ` before the code above.

Comment: the value column in my case is text column and max is not allowed on it. Further  rather than getting  one row I am getting 3 rows with null for other two columns                                                                            Column1   Column2       Column3
 Value1            NULL           NULL
NULL  Value2   NULL
NULL NULL   Value3